# Formatting datetime query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

How do I convert a datetime from a `DB::raw` query of a time difference? For example:

The difference between `exam_start_date` and `exam_end_date` is by 50 seconds and the format is `00:00:50` but when I export it to excel it just returns the seconds only like `50`

How do I keep the initial format in the view for excel?

Comment: Convert into varchar

Comment: I think this could be an excel problem. You should take a look at the cell format. Right click the column in excel en click "format cell's" the category selected there will influence the format to.

Comment: How are you exporting this data to an excel?

Comment: can you shareyour code?

Comment: Can you share the code that you are passing to the view?